# Where to download compete set of data dumps?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, data-dump, beta-sites

It was a hard task to find the download link for the data dump of SE, but I've finally managed it. But after download I've noticed that the dump is far from complete! For example, a dump of The Great Outdoors is missing, which is very well established site, although still in beta.

Where can I find the complete set of data dumps for all SE sites, including betas and closed ones? I know that I can download dumps of closed sites finding their descriptions on Area51, but they must be somewhere aggregated, or?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Active beta sites are intentionally excluded from the data dump, and their data is not made available until they graduate or the site is closed.

Currently, there is not a package that aggregates the data dumps for all closed beta sites.

Comment: Yeah, pretty much this - beta sites are not included.

Comment: It's very sad... Do you have some link to the statement of SE team justifying that intention?

Comment: @ŁukaszLech It's administrative overhead, getting new sites into the data dumps has historically been a bit time consuming and doing it for every single new site just isn't feasible.  We do, however, make all sites (even private betas) [available in the API](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/); depending on the use case, it may be an adequate replacement for a data dump.